# Branch static OID from instance/dynamic OID

Tags: snmp, mib

I would like to know if/how it is possible to branch an OID off of an OID that is dynamic.

Numerically:
`.1.3.6.1.4.1.(PEN).1.1.(variable OID).1.1.1`

Applied:
`.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.company.category.device.deviceinstance.property.sensor.level`
where *deviceinstance* is a **unique ID**.

If there are no device instances, the rest of the branch, `.property.sensor.level`, does not exist.  In other words, the appended OID structure is built on a *per instance* basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by defining MIB table. I would use something like this:

```
deviceInstancesTable OBJECT-TYPE
      SYNTAX   SEQUENCE OF deviceInstanceEntry
      ACCESS   not-accessible
      STATUS   mandatory
      ::= { device 1 }

deviceInstanceEntry OBJECT-TYPE
      SYNTAX   DeviceInstanceEntry
      ACCESS   not-accessible
      STATUS   mandatory
      INDEX    { deviceInstanceIndex }
      ::= { deviceInstancesTable 1 }

DeviceInstanceEntry::=
      SEQUENCE {
         deviceInstanceIndex INTEGER,
         property            DisplayString,
         sensor              DisplayString,
         level               INTEGER,
         deviceInstanceRowStatus        RowStatus
         }
```

So you can create instances dynamically using RowStatus.

Comment: Can I dynamically set OIDs this way?  i.e. use a variable for an OID instead of a specific number?

Comment: You can have any indexes,and any number of index fields/columns, not only numbers

Comment: So if I had a tree that needed to be of the form `.1.3.5.1.4.1.(my PEN).1.1.[unknown value].[unknown value].1.1`, I could accomplish that with this?  "unknown value" could possibly be retrieved from a file, if necessary, but cannot be stated explicitly as it may be based off of something such as an IP address or other UID.

Comment: In SNMP you can use IP addresses, OIDs and even OCTET STRINGs as indexes. So there is no problem.

Comment: Can the actual value of the IP/OID/OCTET STRING be unknown to the MIB and still work?
i.e. In my MIB: staticNode (whatever required syntax) ::= { aWildcardNode 1 }
......where: aWildcardNode (whatever required syntax) ::= { anotherNode undefinedValue } ......if this is indeed possible, could you add an example in your answer?  It would be greatly appreciated!